# Making A Game in Javascript, Wondering why my object speeds up every-time I press the left or right arrow button

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

It is just the beginning process of the game, but I am wondering why my rectangle speeds up every time I press the left or right arrow button. I just want to make is move a little and stop when the buttons are released and have the same speed every-time.

```
    <body>
    <canvas height="400" width="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas>       
    <script>
        "use strict"
        var a=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var c=a.getContext("2d");
        var shipX=180;
        var speed=1;
        c.fillStyle="white";
        c.beginPath();
        c.rect(shipX,350,40,30);
        c.fill();
        c.closePath();
        
        window.onkeydown=function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==37){
                 speed=-1;
                 window.setInterval(moveShip,17);
            }
            if(e.keyCode==39){
                speed=1;
                window.setInterval(moveShip,17);
            }
        }
        
        window.onkeyup=function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==37){
                speed=0;
            }
            if(e.keyCode==39){
                speed=0;
            }
        }
        
        
        function moveShip(){
            shipX+=speed; 
            c.clearRect(0,350,400,50);
            c.fillStyle="white";
            c.beginPath();
            c.rect(shipX,350,40,30);
            c.fill();
            c.closePath();
    }
        
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You never clear any of the intervals...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the repeat key. If keys are held down a long time. The event is triggered repeatedly. So the set interval function is being called multiple times, each of which moves your ship. So either check if the the speed is 0 with an if statement in the keydown event or use a boolean to keep track of what is currently pressed.

Edit: and as @jonrsharpe says. Clear your intervals after releasing the key.

Its best to have just 1 interval running anyways to use as your main thread/loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'setInterval' function in your `moveShip` function causes the function to run multiple instances simultaneously, you see the result of running a few copies of the function by changing the `speed` variable, and then several functions execute the row `shipX + = speed;`

I checked your code using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and it works properly:

```js
 "use strict"
        const STEP_SPEED = 5;
        const SHIP_FILL_COLOR = 'red';
        var a=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var c=a.getContext("2d");
        var shipX=180;
        var speed=1;
        
        moveShip();
        
        window.onkeydown=function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==37){
                 speed=-STEP_SPEED;
                 window.setTimeout(moveShip,17);
            }
            if(e.keyCode==39){
                speed=STEP_SPEED;
                window.setTimeout(moveShip,17);
            }
        }
        
        window.onkeyup=function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==37){
                speed=0;
            }
            if(e.keyCode==39){
                speed=0;
            }
        }
        
        
        function moveShip(){
            shipX+=speed; 
            c.clearRect(0,350,400,50);
            c.fillStyle=SHIP_FILL_COLOR;
            c.beginPath();
            c.rect(shipX,350,40,30);
            c.fill();
            c.closePath();
    }
```

```html
    <canvas height="400" width="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

(jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/YaakovHatam/mf1cL7n5/5/ )